# Access local storage data in iframe

Tags: iframe, local-storage, mode

I make a nav bar who contain a button on click it's toggle class of body to change mode like dark to light . But I used an iframe to access another html file who contain body, section, footer but when I click on nav button it not change color of iframe html. Can you please give some hint . And by the way I use only html pages not any website.

I try to make a nav button who access local storage and change body class of iframe html. I also tried to connect same css and js to get but not working?